# Handling word boudaries in regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

In the string below, I am trying to match the stand alone `Inc.`s.

```
Inc. aa Inc. bbbInc. Inc.
```

The following regular expressions didn't work:

```
/\bInc\.\b/       # got zero matches
/\bInc\.(\b|$)/   # matched the last Inc.
```

I think it is because `\b` matches boundaries between word and non word characters, where I have a `\b` after the `\.`, which is a non word character. I tweaked it to make it work.

```
/\bInc\.($|\W)/
/\bInc\.\B/
```

- I am having trouble understanding why the 4th expression works.
- Which approach among 3 and 4 has least edge cases?
- Is there a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted to match `"Inc."` followed by a non-word character. Since `"."` is a non-word character, What you expect at the ending boundary is a `\W\W` sequence (or the end of the string). `\b` matches the boundary of either a `\w\W` or `\W\w` sequence, so its match will not intersect with the expected match.

The fourth expression works because `\B` matches the boundary of either a `\w\w` sequence or a `\W\W` sequence (or the beginning or the end of a string), and since "." matches `\W`, the `\.\B` match is narrowed down to `\W\W` (or the end of a string), which you wanted.

Comparing the third and the fourth expressions, the third one has two problems. (1) Notice that `\W` matches a string. So `/\bInc\.($|\W)/` will include within the match the character that follows the part you want. In order to avoid this, you can use a lookahead: `/\bInc\.(?=$|\W)/`, but compared to that, the fourth one is much better. (2) Although it is not a problem with your particular example, when the string goes beyond a single line, `$` will not correctly match the end of the string. Using `\z` is better.

I cannot think of a one better than your fourth one.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Perl regex documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions)

> A word boundary (\b ) is a spot between two characters that has a \w on one side of it and a \W on the other side of it (in either order), counting the imaginary characters off the beginning and end of the string as matching a \W .

since `\w` represents `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` `\b` wont match the . as you correctly assume.

```
\bInc\.\B
```

Will match `Inc..`, or any non \w character after `Inc.` same goes for

```
\bInc\.($|\W)
```

If you want to match `Inc.` followed by a whitespace or a newline I'd use

```
\bInc\.(\s|$)
```